# Doctrine 2 Entities ".php~" Files

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, swagger

```
Zend 2 latest
Doctrine 2 latest
Swagger latest
Windows Xampp
Php 5.6
Netbeans latest
```

If i generate my entities, i always get my entity files updated, and additionaly, a `{EntityName}.php~` file is generated (mostly with the exact same file content).

Sometimes the `.php~` files are outdated - like a older version of the entity.

As i use swagger in my project, which will read all entities of the given folder, it always complains about double definition entities..

Why does the `.php~` files happen, and how can i stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "--no-backup" argument when generating the entities with the command

Comment: a pitty that this isnt documented.at least i didn't find anything about this behavior - thank you